# Nuxt plugin - API call only server side but inject server & client side

Tags: nuxt.js

I have an API call in a plugin and inject the data.
This works the only problem is that the API call is being done on server and on client.

```js
export default async (context, inject) => {
  const api_data = await fetch('data')
  inject('config', api_data)
}
```

If I wrap it in a conditional or set the mode through `nuxt.config.js` like so:

```js
// inside plugin
if (process.server) {...}

// OR set the plugins mode in nuxt.config.js
plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/server-only.js', mode: 'server' }]
```

Then it is properly injected `Server Side` but is not longer available on `Client Side` and breaks.

How can I "cache" the API call from server side and reuse it for client side?

Comment: Why would you need it client side while allowing it to run only server side? Also, you could remove `mode: server`here maybe.

Comment: I need it server side to prerender the html. But then client side it throws an error because it's not injected. Example: Userdata and preferences.